# Wordpress static home page dynamic posts page url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Hi I have a Wordpress installation with a static main page and posts page with the name articles.

My custom permalink string within Wordpress is set to   `/%postname%`

and my htaccess file is set as follows:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

When I browse to the articles page, my url rewrite looks like this:

`example.com/articles/page/5`

**EDIT -----**
The articles page is the one that I use to browse all articles with a *previous article* and a *next article* link.

Thus next article would give me `example.com/articles/page/6` and previous article would bring me to `example.com/articles/page/4`

however I would like the "page" part to change to article and the "number" to the actual particle name.
**EDIT ------ END**

I would like to get a setting as follows:

`example.com/articles/article/the-article-name`

how would I achive this?

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache, is mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: @Chrostopher Altman - mod_rewrite must be turned on since the post is in the /articles/page/5 format, else it would be example.com/?page_id=5

Answer (score 0):

Try a trailing slash on your permalink setting: `/%postname%/`

**Edit 5/02/10:**

Check your .htaccess for multiple, conflicting rewrite blocks.

If want this: `/articles/article/name-of-article`

The set "articles" as your category base and put all articles in a category called "article":

[Posts Categories SubPanel « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Categories_SubPanel)

And then your paging will be in the format  page/2/, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all your posts are essentially 'articles' (i.e. you don't mind having 'articles' in the URL for all post-related permalinks - categories, tags, single posts etc.), then simply set your permalink structure to;

```
/articles/%category%/%postname/
```

Obviously if you want the structure `articles/article/post-name/`, you'll have to file posts in a category with slug 'article'.

Comment: There is a slug "page" already which I would like to replace with any other word, say "article" ...